# Can MySQL commit fail if individual queries works?

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, commit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a COMMIT statement (in SQL) ever fail? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960189/can-a-commit-statement-in-sql-ever-fail-how)

Can a commit query fail if all queries within the transaction returned a working result?

I have a `$ok = mysql_query($query);` on all queries inside the transaction, but I do not have a `$ok = mysql_query("COMMIT");` since I thought that if the individual queries work.

Using innodb.

Comment: may be out of system failure ,whats your auto commit status?set it to false before transaction

Comment: Same problem as the other topic but this is with MySQL, not SQL or PostgreSQL

Comment: @unska There's no difference in the reasons why a `commit` might fail.

Comment: I tried deliberately to crash a commit but the row lock seems to handle everything I try to throw at it. So the question still remains: can a commit fail if all queries inside the transaction works and returns correct data?