# Sequel transaction covers errors during commit

Tags: sql, ruby, transactions, sequel

I'm using Sequel to access MySql and SQL Server databases.

Sequel allows me to do transactions like this:

```
@client = Sequel.connect(config)
@client.transaction do
    @client.execute("DELETE FROM UserGroup WHERE UserId = #{user_id}")
    @client.execute("DELETE FROM User WHERE Id = #{user_id}")
end
```

So, if something goes wrong with my queries, the transaction will roll back and everything will be ok.

If my queries are OK, but at the moment of the commit something goes wrong on the database and the commit fails, will the Ruby code detect that and fail too?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960189/can-a-commit-statement-in-sql-ever-fail-how

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how the database adapter is implemented. It might throw an exception, which would be different than `Sequel::Rollback`. Therefore, it won't be caught by the `transaction` method and would bubble up to your code.

But normally, problems occur during the operations within the transaction, and not during the COMMIT itself. Normally you should not worry about it.